# how to generate AES Secret key in objective c?

Tags: java, objective-c, security, cryptography, encryption-symmetric

How to generate java equivalent secret key in objective C?

```
public SecretKey getSymmetricKey(String keyString) {
    SecretKey secretKey = null;
    try {
        byte[] raw = Base64.decode(keyString);
        secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
        System.out.println("key "+secretKey);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return secretKey;
}
```

Here is java code

Output - key javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec@17050

please help me on this how to implement above in objective c??

Comment: That code does not generate a key; it merely Base64 decodes a string and creates a new instance of SecretKeySpec with the decoded bytes. Either way, what do you have in Objective-C at the moment?

Comment: @ntoskrnl     NSString *inputStr = @"Nitesh";
    NSString *base64EncodedStr = [inputStr base64EncodedString];
    NSLog(@"Base64 Encoding of string - %@",base64EncodedStr);
    NSData *inputData = [base64EncodedStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
I m doing this for base64 conversion of key but I dnt know equivalent of SecretKey in objective.

Comment: SecretKeySpec is just an API detail. The APIs are obviously not identical between different languages. Instead of translating the code line-by-line, you should check what the Objective-C cryptography API looks like. Also note that in general, it is not recommended to do manual cryptography like this, unless you are very familiar with what you are doing.

Comment: @ntoskrnl yes I know it is not possible to find line by line replacement of java code I am just asking for suggestions or guidance, which iOS API will work for implementing this...